# Xamarin.Android didn't find class from dynamic library loading

Tags: c#, android, dynamic, dll, xamarin.android

I got a bugs when I create an Instance from a Xamarin Android Class Library  by dynamic loading. This class implement and Interface and I use this instance via interface.
Everything works fine, until this class call to create an instance of a BroacastReceiver class. it throw an exception:
[debu log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHaTP.png)

I spent all day long to find out, and did some way, but nothing happens...
also, I guest the bug come from "DexPathList[[directory "."]". As my look into other issues on google, the directory never get empty like this, ooppssssssssss
Please help me, if you guys know how to fix it.

thanks.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a linker issue if the class library is being loaded dynamically. The linker uses static analysis to remove assemblies that it thinks aren't used. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker)

Comment: What are the current linker settings in the Android project options? Don't Link (None in Visual Studio), Link SDK Assemblies (Sdk Assemblies Only) or Link All Assemblies (Sdk and User Assemblies)?

Comment: the Current linker I'm using is SDK Assemplies Only. But I tried other options and nothing change, same issue. Help me please

Comment: @Sjolfr do you think that I should to set linker to none?

Comment: I see your debug log, your lack the class, Linker will excude some class when complie, please set it to None, if this issue is still existed.

Comment: Try setting it to none so we can see if the Linker is the problem.

Comment: I've tried None already, but nothing change. the debug log is the same @@@

Comment: If you call the BroacastReceiver class in the activity, such as MainActivity, If you will get this error?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT the broacastReceiver is not call from an activity. But I just create an instance, not register it